# Get parameter name of object to inject

Tags: c#, ninject

I have an interface named `IListener`. Now I want to create a class that receives to instances of that interface.

```
public Controller(IListener listener1, IListener listener2)
{ ... }
```

The implementation of `IListener` needs a port. How can I determine the parameter name in the binding of `IListener` so I can choose my appropriate port? I think the callback could look like:

```
    public Kernel()
    {
        Bind<IListener>()
            .To<SyncUdpListener>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("port", GetListenerPort);
    }

    private object GetListenerPort(IContext context, ITarget target)
    {
        var command = this.Get<Command>();

        switch (...)
        {
            case "videoListener":
                return command.VideoPort;
            case "audioListener":
                return command.AudioPort;
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Where I need to fill in the parameter name in the switch statement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I`m not 100% percent sure what you want to achieve here. But if your controller looks like:

```
public Controller(IListener videoListener, IListener audioListener)
{ ... }
```

And with the following code:

```
private object GetListenerPort(IContext context, ITarget target)
{
    var command = this.Get<Command>();

    switch (context.Request.Target.Name)
    {
        case "videoListener":
            return command.VideoPort;
        case "audioListener":
            return command.AudioPort;
    }

    throw new Exception();
}
```

You will get a controller with two `IListener` instance with the VideoPort, and AudioPort parameters. And maybe you have to make sure that the `Request.Target.Type` is the right controller type.